# IEEE 754-2008 standard order preserved under multiplication

Tags: ieee-754, multiplication

In the IEEE standard for floating point arithmetic is the ordering of floating point numbers preserved under multiplication.  For instance, let a, x and y be floating point numbers is it guaranteed that

if x < y  then ax < ay ?

It would certainly be strange if this was not true, but I would like some reassurance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that in your question, the multiplier is positive.

The answer is no.

First, it is always possible for the products to underflow or overflow. In this case they are rounded to 0 or to +infinity, and the inequality is violated.

As for the more general case: since results are always correctly rounded, and the unrounded value of `ax` is less than the unrounded value of `ay`, the rounded value of ax can not be greater than the rounded value of `y`. This still leaves the possibility that one is rounded up and the other rounded down and the rounded values would be equal.

This can only happen if `x` and `y` are successive floating-point numbers. Otherwise the difference is always greater than 1 unit in the last place, and the numbers cannot be rounded the same.

And unfortunately, sometimes this does happen. Take for example:

```
x = 1.2345678899999997
y = 1.23456789
a = 0.84812721230468113
```

then both `ax` and `ay` are equal to `1.047070622946572`.

Comment: +1, though note that if the results of the multiplications are denormal, it is possible for this to happen even if `x` and `y` are not successive floating-point numbers.  Also the answer is trivially "no" if `a` is zero, infinity, or NaN.